# Check if array already exists in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, list, session

In Visual C#, how can I detect if an array already exists in Session? The Website has a TextBox were you can write a name. When you click the button "Click" it adds the name in the Label. Let's say I add the same Name and it should show me a message in the Label like "Name already exists!". What should I do? I read  about the "contains" method, but didn't worked so well for me. What mistake do I make?

The following code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["listOfCharacters"] == null) 
        {
            Session.Add("listOfCharacters", new List<Character>());
        }

        List<Character> listOfCharacters = (List<Character>)Session["listOfCharacters"];

        listOfCharacters.Add(new Character() { name = txtName.Text});

        lblShow.Text = "";

        foreach (Character item in listOfCharacters)
        {
            lblShow.Text += "Name: " + item.name + "<br />";

        //if (listOfCharacters.Contains(Session["listOfCharacters"]))
        //{
        //    lblShow.Text = "Exists";
        //}
        }
    }
}
```

Believe me, it took me hours and days, but haven't found a solution for it yet.

Comment: How many names do you want to keep in your session? Just 1 (the last one) or more? And what does the `Character` class do?

Comment: I want to Keep more then one Name. The character class is simply just this: public class Character
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

Comment: I that case I would suggest you would read the second part of my answer and go with the `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write LINQ query for checking if the item exists in the list

e.g.

```
private string _listofcharacters = "listOfCharacters";
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session[_listofcharacters] == null)
    {
        Session.Add(_listofcharacters, new List<Character>());
    }

    List<Character> listOfCharacters = (List<Character>)Session[_listofcharacters];

    lblShow.Text = "";

    var check = from p in listOfCharacters
                where p.Name.ToLower().Contains(txtName.Text.ToLower())
                select p;

    if (check.Count() == 0)
    {
        listOfCharacters.Add(new Character() { Name = txtName.Text });

        foreach (Character item in listOfCharacters)
        {
            lblShow.Text += "Name: " + item.Name + "<br />";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblShow.Text = "Name already exists!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uou have to itterate throught your list and see of the property `name` of Character are the same to the new text in the textbox. You could use LINQ:

```
if (listOfCharacters.Any(c => c.name == txtName.Text)) 
    lblShow.Text = "Name already exists!";
```

If you were using `List<string>` then it would be easier, because than you could just use the `Contains` method like this:

```
List<string> listOfCharacters = ...
....
if (listOfCharacters.Contains(txtName.Text)) 
    lblShow.Text = "Name already exists!";
```

For extra performance, no not use `List<string>` but `HashSet<string>`.

So if you are just having a character class to contain the name, then I would suggest: lose the class and go with the `List<string>`.

Your code would then become:

```
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> listOfNames = Session["listOfNames"] as List<string>;
    if (listOfNames == null)
        Session["listOfNames"] = listOfNames = new List<string>();

    if (listOfNames.Contains(txtName.Text))
    {
        lblShow.Text = "Name already exists!";
    }
    else
    {
        listOfNames.Add(txtName.Text);
        lblShow.Text = String.Join("<br />", listOfNames);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Spending hours and days without result was really a pain. Deeply appreciate yours and everyones help :)

Comment: What else is to do, if I have a second declaration called "age" in my Character class?:     public int age { get; set; } How can I Display both(Name & age)? Trying a few things out, but it Shows me an error: 

System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.String]
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Int32]

Answer (score 0):

Entity:

```
public class Character
{
    public string Name;
}
```

Comparer

```
public class CharacterComparer : IEqualityComparer<Character>
{
    public bool Equals(Character x, Character y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Ignore case and culture
        return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Character obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Name))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

use HashSet.

```
        HashSet<Character> characters1 = new HashSet<Character>(new CharacterComparer());
        characters1.Add(new Character {Name = "Alex"});
        characters1.Add(new Character { Name = "Peter" });
        characters1.Add(new Character { Name = "John" });

        HashSet<Character> characters2 = new HashSet<Character>(new CharacterComparer());
        characters2.Add(new Character { Name = "John" });
        characters2.Add(new Character { Name = "Jenny" });

        characters2.IntersectWith(characters1);

        Console.WriteLine("Existing count: " + characters2.Count);
```

Output:

```
Existing count: 1
```

**EDIT 1**

And do not add new item in session's list:

```
 listOfCharacters.Add(new Character() { name = txtName.Text});
```

You've already added new Character to list and then tries to find it in the same list. You should use separate lists. Session's list (existing Characters) and new List with Characters to be added.

add

```
using System.Linq;
```

and iterate through new list to search existing users in Session's list

```
// characters2 = created new list with Characters to be added
foreach (var item in characters2)
{
    Character character = item;
    // characters1 = obtained from sessions
    bool contains = characters1.Contains(character, new CharacterComparer());
    if (contains)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Character {0} exists", character.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply check if the session is Null or Empty. You can use the IsNullOrEmpty function of the string object.

```
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["listOfCharacters"] as string)){
          lblShow.Text = "Exists";
  }
```

There are similar questions on Stackoverflow though.

Comment: -1: Now you are checking if there is a value inside the session of type string. But since OP is using a `List<Characters>` your condition will always result in `False`.